# Weird Sales tax Rounding error when rounding to the nearest .05 in C#

Tags: c#, rounding

I'm working on a c# application that takes in a few item prices and calculate sales tax.  The application works perfectly, however I'm having problem calculating sales tax to the nearest .05, I have been using this function to do this.

```
 public decimal customRound(decimal num)
    {
        return Math.Round(num * 20.0M) / 20.0M;
    }
```

However it's not doing what it's supposed to be doing.

Example 47.50 * 15(tax) / 100 = 7.125(total tax) 
If you pass 7.125 it rounds it to 7.1 instead of 7.15. Resulting in a final price of 54.60 instead of 54.65!!!

Comment: Try this - Math.Round(num * 20.0M, 2)

Comment: Or Math.Round((num * 20.0M) / 20.0M, 2)

Comment: The 2nd parameter for math.round should be the number of decimal places.

Comment: Reference: [MSDN: Math.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Math.Round%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Be sure to write unit-tests for this (the solution you end up with), if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2):

[The default rounding method used for `Math.Round` is ToEven.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

You want to use `AwayFromZero`. Use it like this:

```
public decimal customRound(decimal num)
        {
            return Math.Round(num * 20.0M, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / 20.0M;
        }
```

More info on rounding numbers can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding).

Comment: This assumes that the OP actually intended to round to an integer

Comment: How does that asume the OP wants to round to an integer? Result of Math.Round is a decimal, and it is divided by 20.0. Perfect logic for rounding to intervals of .05.

Comment: Math.Round defaults to 0 digits. This will round to an integer (143). The original code rounds to 142.  It looks though that only rounding to an integer will return the result the OP wanted

Comment: Math.Round called with a decimal, will round to a decimal with value 143, divided by 20 = 1.75, exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: Indeed, like other commenters I saw the decimals, not the requirement to round to `.05`